# Does "height" shown in Google Chrome Inspector include border?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Hovering over an element in Chrome inspector shows its height and width:

[image: Chrome inspector demo]

Under "styles" it also shows the computed height and width.

My question is: which "height" and "width" is this? Does it include the border?

Comment: @Paulie_D no, it shows the hover over on the element.

Comment: OH...I get it. Apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That width and height popover does not include `margin` or `position`.

The width and height shown in the popover is the `width` and `height` added with the `padding` and `border` of the element.

The full individual amounts are be shown in the computed section but with some basic addition, you should be able to see that the popover values are `width` + `l-r padding` + `l-r border` and the same for the height.

[image]

As shown, the core `width` and `height` are enclosed within the `padding` and `border` which is surrounded by a solid line.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't include position?

Comment: Css position attributes. Top left right bottom. They are not included in the border-box.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to include the border. Right click > inspect element > change the border width manually, and this becomes apparent.